# Grails custom tag library out multiple lines

Tags: taglib

I am making a custom tag library in which I have to output html contents to the view using tag library. And we can output the contents like-

```
def globalCSS = { attrs, body ->
    out << '<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->'
    out << '<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css', file: 'font-awesome.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons', file: 'simple-line-icons.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/uniform/css', file: 'uniform.default.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->'
}
```

Now the problem is that if I try to enter multiple lines in one `out` then it throws an error that-

```
def globalCSS = { attrs, body ->
    out << 'Bla bla bla
    Super bla bla
    Awesome bla bla'
}
```

Error-

```
Multiple markers at this line
- implements groovy.lang.Script.run
- Groovy:expecting ''', found '\r' @ line 10,
```

So is there anyway to post multiple lines in one out? As it would be easy for me to copy paste the HTML code which I need to output so please suggest a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString for the section `Multiline Strings`.  Use `'''` or `"""` to sourround multi line strings in groovy.

> If you have a block of text which you wish to use but don't want to have to encode it all (e.g. if its a block of HTML or something) then you can use the `"""` syntax.
>
> ```
>  def text = """\
>  hello there ${name}
>  how are you today?
>  """
> ```

The trailing `\` in the first line means, that the linebreak there should be ignored (for readability)

Comment: Superb. Thanks it was simple and sweet.